# copy GPO from 2 csv files loop issue

Tags: powershell

I have 2 csv files, one with the Win7 GPOs display name and another with the Win10 display name. I want to loop through both csv so that I can copy the GPO settings from Win7 to a new Win10 display name GPO. When I run my loop, it applies the same 1st win7 GPO to all new Win10 GPOs, then the second etc... I've looked around but I can't seem to get a tip. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import-module grouppolicy
import-module activedirectory

$Win7GPOPath = "c:\temp\copyWin7GPOs.csv"
$Win10GPOPath = "c:\temp\copyWin10GPOs.csv"

$7GPO = @{}
$10GPO = @{}

$Win7GPO = import-csv $Win7GPOPath
$Win10GPO = import-csv $Win10GPOPath

ForEach($7GPO in $Win7GPO) {


    ForEach($10GPO in $Win10GPO) {

    Write-Output "Copy-GPO -SourceName $7GPO -TargetName $10GPO"
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your CSV files contain the exact same number of rows and each row in one file corresponds to that same row number in the other file, you can use one `for` loop.

```
import-module grouppolicy
import-module activedirectory

$Win7GPOPath = "c:\temp\copyWin7GPOs.csv"
$Win10GPOPath = "c:\temp\copyWin10GPOs.csv"

$7GPO = @{}
$10GPO = @{}

$Win7GPO = import-csv $Win7GPOPath
$Win10GPO = import-csv $Win10GPOPath

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Win7GPO.count; $i++) {
   Copy-GPO -SourceName $Win7GPO[$i] -TargetName $Win10GPO[$i]
}
```

If the CSV file contains a header, you will need to reference that header property like `$Win7GPO[$i].Property`.

Comment: Wow, many thanks AdmonOfThings for your insight :-) Really appreciated :-) I will get into the for loop. Have a pleasant day :-)